# Syllabification of "riding"

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, phonetics, syllables

According to the *Middle Consonant Rule*, shouldn't we syllabicate the word *riding* as **Ri-ding** (**raɪ-dɪŋ**)? Why are we syllabicating it as **Rid-ing** (**raɪd.ɪŋ**)? What's the rule for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's syllabified as **raɪd.ɪŋ** because there's a [morpheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morpheme) boundary between the two syllables (the *-ing* is a different morpheme). Morpheme boundaries can override other syllabification rules and morpheme boundaries are usually syllable boundaries, so it's syllabified that way.

According to Prof John Wells:

> In polymorphemic words, consonants belong to the syllable appropriate to the morpheme of which they form a part. This applies only to synchronic, psychologically real morphemes.
>
> [[Wells Syllabification - UCL](https://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/syllabif.htm)]